# understanding app engine memcache statistics

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached, google-cloud-platform

Under **Compute > Memcache** we have some statistics:

**HitRatio, Items In Cache, Oldest Item Age, Total Cache Size** etc.

Then we can also see stats for 20 commonly used keys ordered by either **Operation Count** or **Memcache compute units**

my question is, is it possible to figure out how many times per second a key has been read (or read + written) from memcache using just memcache stats?

For example, if i have **1 million hits** and the **oldest item is 1 day old**, and my **memecache key uses 5% of the traffic**,

Could I go **(1 million hits  *  5%  = 50,000 hits) / 24 hours = 0.57 hits per second**.

Really I have no idea what the statistics on the memcache viewer actually mean - For example the statistics don't even reset if memcache is flushed.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure counting this way won't return what you want. As explained in the [python memcache statistic paragraph](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/#Python_Statistics), the age of your items reset when they are read. So the oldest item being 1 day old just means it has been in memcache for a day since it was read.

To figure out how many times a second a key has been read, you might want to use a [sharding counter](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters), or some other form of [logging](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/logging), then retrieving the logged data with the [Logs API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/logs/) to interpret them. It can't really be done directly from the memcache statistics (might be an interesting feature to request on Google's [Public Issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list) though)